# How to test for undef when running whois in Perl?

Tags: perl, variables, return, whois

In the following code example, I am trying to get a whois statement. Every now and then it throws a timeout exception. From [PerlDoc](http://search.cpan.org/~corris/Net-Whois-Raw-0.23/lib/Net/Whois/Raw.pm) it says that in cases the `$Net::Whois::Raw::CHECK_FAIL = 1;` is set to `1` then it should return `undef`.

I encapsulated the whois with eval so it will nto break the script, and then I added a `sleep` and then I attempt to get the whois again. But it throws a warning "`...isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)`".

So again, I un the run, and when it gets to the `if` it stills executes the code in there, and throws that error I mentioned above. How can I safetly evaluate the `undef` when it happens?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use Net::Whois::Raw;
#use Net::Whois::Parser;
use Data::Dumper;

$Net::Whois::Raw::OMIT_MSG = 2; 
$Net::Whois::Raw::CHECK_FAIL = 1; 
$Net::Whois::Raw::TIMEOUT = 30;

my $domainName = "google.com";
my $domainInfo;

while (1) {
    eval {
        $domain_info = whois($domainName);
    };

    if (undef == $domain_info) { 
        sleep (10); 
        eval {
            $domain_info = whois($domainName);
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`==` performs a numerical comparison. Its operands are coerced into numbers if they are not. It's not appropriate to use `==` here. To check if a scalar is defined or not, use [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html).

```
my $domain_info;
while (1) {
    $domain_info = eval { whois($domainName) };
    last if defined($domain_info);
    sleep(10); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
 if (undef == $domain_info) {
```

with

```
if (not defined $domain_info) {
```

to check whether variable is not [defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html).

`==` is for comparing two numbers.

Comment: I will test it once I get the failure to break the script again. Thanks